# How to merge two similar objects in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, object

please i need help here. I have two similar objects and i want to merge them into one object in laravel. How is it done?

Here are my objects

```
{"course_code":"UGRC110","venue_id":22,"exam_date":"May 6, 2017","exam_time":"3:30 pm","student_no":400}
```

and

```
{"course_code":"UGRC110","venue_id":25,"exam_date":"May 6, 2017","exam_time":"3:30 pm","student_no":700}
```

I want to merge and get something like this

```
{"course_code":"UGRC110","venue_id":[22,25],"exam_date":"May 6, 2017","exam_time":"3:30 pm","student_no":[400,700]}
```

I want to get the venue_id and student_no merged together.. any help will be
much appreciated.. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like you should just json_decode, then `array_merge($json1['venue_id'], $json2['venue_id'])` and `array_merge($json1['student_no'], $json2['student_no'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you out. Here we are using just simple `foreach` to merge these two `json`'s.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785689)

```
<?php

$json1 = '{"course_code":"UGRC110","venue_id":22,"exam_date":"May 6, 2017","exam_time":"3:30 pm","student_no":400}';
$json2 = '{"course_code":"UGRC110","venue_id":25,"exam_date":"May 6, 2017","exam_time":"3:30 pm","student_no":700}';

json_merge($json1, $json2);
function json_merge($json1, $json2)
{
    $array1 = json_decode($json1, true);
    $array2 = json_decode($json2, true);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($array1[$key] == $array2[$key])
        {
            $result[$key] = $array2[$key];
        } else
        {
            $result[$key][] = $array1[$key];
            $result[$key][] = $array2[$key];
        }
    }
    return json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "course_code": "UGRC110",
    "venue_id": [
        22,
        25
    ],
    "exam_date": "May 6, 2017",
    "exam_time": "3:30 pm",
    "student_no": [
        400,
        700
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wow.. that great.. Thank you @Sahil ...... Anyway please dont they have any laravel collection method that can perform similar function without me having to loop over the objects. I want a very efficient method cos i will be applying it on thousands of records from my database

Comment: @Ernesto laravel does not have a method which will do this think, You can change my code to php function which can be used multiple times.

Comment: @Ernesto You can do it this way... I have edit my post hope that will help you out....

Comment: Thanks once again @Sahil